# What is this eror?

Tags: c#

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Suppression State
Error       Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\36.exe" to "bin\Debug\36.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\36.exe' because it is being used by another process.    36

Comment: probably Visual Studio has locked the previous build. So try again, or restart VS

Comment: looks to me likes youre compiling an application while it is still running thus preventing you from copying the exe

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971049/visual-studio-cannot-copy-after-build

Answer (score 0):

Open TaskManager on windows, in Processes Tab find your app and select End.
so Rebuild your project.

[image: Like That]